# Calculate the average of the 3 highest grades

Tags: excel

I'm relatively new to excel but I am making a gradebook that calculates all of my grades.

One of my classes has an interesting way to calculate grades. There are 4 quizzes, and the lowest one will be dropped (essentially removed from the calculation completely).

How would I go about this, I tried using

```
=((SUM(D2:D5)-SUM(SMALL(D2:D5,4)))/(COUNT(D2:D5)*100))
```

on data like this

```
D2|75
D3|80
D4|83
D5|65
```

So in this case, I want the 65 to be removed, then calculate the average

I am not getting any error but the average is wrong

Comment: try `(sum(d2:d5)-min(d2:d5))/3 * 100`

Comment: Like Ilya said.  Also note that small(D2:D5,4) returns the 4th smallest (i.e. the largest value, not the smallest).

Comment: @IlyaBursov had the correct answer (as well as acfrancis) below. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract 1 from the count. In the example you are dividing by 4 instead of 3.

Like this:

```
=((SUM(D2:D5)-MIN(D2:D5))/(COUNT(D2:D5) - 1) * 100
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! (Will select as best answer once time limit is over)

Answer (score 2):

You can average the top 3 out of 4 with this formula

`=AVERAGE(LARGE(D2:D5,{1,2,3}))`

Answer (score 0):

Add the four tests together, subtract out the min(.) of the same range, and divide the total by 3.

If your scores are in B2, C2, D2, and E2 then something like: 
=(SUM(B2:E2)-MIN(B2:E2))/3

Was this helpful?